# How do you turn a function type into its async equivalent in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, promise, async-await

How can I type this function in relation to its input `fn`?

```
function makeAsync(fn) {
  return async (...args) => fn(...args);
}
```

It returns a function identical to its input, but instead of returning `Type` it would return `Promise<Type>`

Usage example:

```
const a = () => 1; // Type () => number;
const b = makeAsync(a); // Type () => Promise<number>;
const c = makeAsync(b); // Type () => Promise<number>; // ✅, not Promise<Promise<number>>
```

This works, but it's a little verbose

```
// Unwraps a Promise<T> value into just T, so we never get Promise<Promise<T>>
type Unpromise<MaybePromise> = MaybePromise extends Promise<infer Type> ? Type : MaybePromise;

// Like ReturnType, except it returns the unwrapped promise also for async functions
type AsyncReturnType<T extends (...args: any[]) => any> = Unpromise<ReturnType<T>>

// For a `() => T` function it returns its async equivalent `() => Promise<T>`
type PromisedFunction<T extends (...args: any[]) => any> =
    (...args: Parameters<T>) => Promise<AsyncReturnType<T>>;
```

```
function makeAsync<T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(fn: T): PromisedFunction<T> {
  return async (...args) => fn(...args);
}
```

[TypeScript Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=15&ssc=2&pln=12&pc=5#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-tzhdAmPhVPBwsWKoJlI9rbaSPbcjtELm6xAGxW4Vrm62XEaIp3S4gkqgmAxBLpEDDa8CZ22iyXuyu1xvwMpt2PsGHyHu50A)

Are there any better/shorter ways to achieve this?

Comment: Would overloading the function for `… => T` and `… => Promise<T>` work?

Comment: The types of my real function are a little complex already, I think adding an overload would not help... but perhaps it's worth a try!

Comment: I'll link to the bug that causes the nonsensical `Promise<Promise<T>>` so in the future a solution could be simpler: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27711

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shorten up the types a bit by defining separate type parameters `A`,`R` for the function parameters and return type, so they are inferred automatically. Then it is easy to just wrap a `Promise` around `R` in `makeAsync2` ([sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=33&ssc=47&pln=28&pc=1#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-tzhdAmPhVPBwoWKoJlI8LVaSDbcjtENmaxA62W4ZrG82XIaIu3i4gkqgmAxBLpEDDq8Cpy2C0XO0uV2vwMpNyPsMHyDuZ0CIJEBahYC5IhErCRcgwjqwTeNWT3rYsuQAExapsDrYm62QJN6voBBmLrzMKCSBsmzqyoh5aatBc77uAwyljKFYBNe8DZDKQEBAI8DsMcQrllW56DicRHgCRZEnBR4BUTRDZNru86CM0uiWgBuJATsuTDsCTHHCxbEYBxlEcNR0C0e6E6XmQJGAgJeGHqu3YDgAzNkVwAESoGZ7rbnxz66VY+nHlYOwmeA5mWdZECTrZ8CAhEQA)):

```
declare function makeAsync2<A extends any[], R>(fn: (...args: A) => R): (...args: A) => Promise<R>

const c = (arg1: number, arg2: string[]) => 1; // (arg1: number, arg2: string) => number
const d = makeAsync2(c); // (arg1: number, arg2: string[]) => Promise<number>
const cResult = c(3, ["s"]) // number
const dResult = d(3, ["s"]) // Promise<number>
```

Edit:

If the input function `fn` potentially can itself return a promise, we can set its return type to the union `R | Promise<R>`([sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=3&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwIYGsCmBBAzgT0gCYAebRTADykzABNdFUx8BtAXQBpEAlAPgAUwMAC5EAgHRTUAJwDmuMdgCUiALx9eiAD6IACjLjIYuTCX7Kxk6fMWIV6zQaMmz-RAG8AUIkQzMUCAySKgEkOJSErIKqhqIwtZRtsoA3F4Avl5eEAi4UIgQ6uLRAIxieTIwYHKxmiUpiAD0jcXyZYgVVTWOiGAgyABGmDLZufl0RWhYeIQQRAIQqU0tAqXlUJXVtfqGxqYkfYPDfKNgeQU8mLggADb5agUCAETAcHBPqs29-UMjOWfjS7XO5FOjPV7vT4tZx7MyHX4nU7nTBFVZtdabbpxGGuCT+XBwG4AN0wAgAzFDWnJ2p0tj0cft4cckflgJMMDgwnMBJgll80dSMV1tgy4T9mf9kUDbvcKOC3h9ljsXIzxTITpLWdKQQ9gPLIUrRQc1XwgA)):

```
function makeAsync2<A extends any[], R>(fn: (...args: A) => R | Promise<R>): (...args: A) => Promise<R> {
  return async (...args) => fn(...args);
}

const e = (arg1: string) => Promise.resolve(3) // (arg1: string) => Promise<number>
const f = makeAsync2(e); // (arg1: string) => Promise<number>
const eResult = e("foo") // Promise<number>
const fResult = f("foo") // Promise<number>
```

Comment: This is not what the OP is looking for. When you call `makeAsync2` on an already-asynchronous function, you get back a `Promise<Promise<R>>` type, correct would be only `Promise<R>`.

Comment: Not sure, if async returning input functions are part of the requirement because of  sentence "a function identical to its input, but instead of returning Type it would return Promise<Type>" - that would indicate the opposite. But you are probably right, `Unpromise` would otherwise not make so much sense. Thanks, gonna update answer.

Comment: That looks good! I was using `Unpromise` exactly to avoid the `Promise<Promise<T>>` you'd get with `Promise<ReturnType< async function here >>`

Comment: `makeAsync2` works as I expect, but I can't seem to apply it to a real function: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTAEBcAsEsGdQO4HsBOBreAzVoCGpZoA7AcwBsBTUIi2cCgE1AAcUkBbOCgKHAE9mVAGJlc4ekQAKbTrAoAeACoA+UAF5Qi0BQAeEhvGkcu83ET6qA-JtAAuUEdkKV3bpgCuRAMbhoSIqDsuGgUAIKwfN4ATPKh2noURAZ45gDaALoANKAASsoAFJhE9vkAdOW4KCSw9qEAlOqqOXV1JeWlldW1DWqqImISjiZ5oADe3KCgKBTg7igBuBHeoGUVVbA9qkWrHet1ANzcAL7cXv502uornQCM9nQoxCSbDjJcpdOwSGQAbhT5AGYGiBrlU7gRwI9SC8hnJ5ER3OwAEYUFDKU7ncCgTBXIIhcKRLxRfIUA6gEH5W73SFPGFvOEI5Go9FnIgXCg5WjuMhYjT-ABE2CQ-OBYFhCkZKLRGLZWMwnNg3N52PygqQwtFr2MDMRUvR3CAA

Comment: @fregante in this case it would be perfectly fine to cast the return type like [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTAEBcAsEsGdQO4HsBOBreAzVoCGpZoA7AcwBsBTUIi2cCgE1AAcUkBbOCgKHAE9mVAGJlc4ekQAKbTrAoAeACoA+UAF5Qi0BQAeEhvGkcu83ET6qA-JtAAuUEdkKV3bpgCuRAMbhoSIqDsuGgUAIKwfN4ATPKh2noURAZ45gDaALoANKAASsoAFJhE9vkAdOW4KCSw9qEAlOqqOXUl5aWV1bUNaqoiYhKOJnmgAN7coKAoFODuKAH5uBHeoGUVVTVx3apFq+3rdQ2LK20dNaD1jaB94omDcvLDANzcAL5AA). It seems, your case can get even easier: TS automatically flattens the `Promise` type with the `async` keyword, so no need for `FlattenPromise` here (updated answer).

Comment: Thank you for your answers! They work great for regular functions, but unfortunately both of our solutions fail on overloaded functions.

Comment: Overloads: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTAEBcAsEsGdQO4HsBOBreAzVoCGpZoA7AcwBsBTUIi2cCgE1AAcUkBbOCgKHAE9mVAGJlc4ekQAKbTrAoAeACoA+UAF5Qi0BQAeEhvGkcu83ET6qA-JtAAuUEdkKV3bpgCuRAMbhoSIqDsuGgUAIKwfN4ATPKh2noURAZ45gDaALoANKAASsoAFJhE9vkAdOW4KCSw9qEAlOqqOXUl5aWV1bUNaqoiYhKOJnmgAN7coKAoFODuKAH5uBHeoGUVVTVx3apFq+3rdQ2LK20dNaD1jaB94omDcvLDANzcAL6ui5FeoB7evv6g0AYiV8-HyOnsdBQxBILQcMhMkOhymeH2WPx8fgCgOB0FB4Oo7nYACMKChYXcFERCSSUMjuKivui-ligUQQXwwfYqcTSaAAD4EcBQ0jk+H3bk0-mC4UkVRjACQUxmc1AOmeb24Xn8dDwSy8jHUgWCYT1UXy2LZuL4dWeWqIOuwSHsFPkEtJqg0DMY+QAjDbNdrwKAiZVnWKFIjSB7dZ9vQBySAUMhkJBxm1AA

Comment: @fregante Puhh, I think you reached the edges of the compiler here. My guess, what happens is: when `makeAsync2(identity)` is invoked, the compiler has no idea, which overload you really want. In this uncertain case, it just chooses the last signature (look [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types)). You can manually set the generics then (example follows, too long text)

Comment: @fregante [TS](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgNgQ2MCA7ACgJwPYFsCWAzhADwAqAfFALxRlQQAeKqAJoVFnkaQqiFQD8dKAC5OOAsXIUAULIBmAV1QBjYPmyoouBAGsIAQUIg1JQw2Zp2UPiADaAXQA0UAEoUAFAtTjPAOkCETABzQnFDAEoaKjcoAB8JbmkPSL9A-2CwiOjqKi4pUg8oAG9ZKChMCGAlTG0EEzUoAKDQwlyqHxbMtsiAblkAX3kG01UoZTUNLSh8VjQNUE9GcUJgTHxUELSkwpI1ja2KAdGmyfVNbTmF-CWVqFQlXAAjCEwdgp4SR5e349lTuNztMrvNUIsQMtxD9XpgElADpttuJPtIYW94YijqVypVqrVtIwBsNZKotGtbI1VBBWAA5J6wmg6fRGKkkezozAuB4Mv6ea7g24gfqk8nACbYbAoyRfTlUWiAmn036YTwARhFotQFMVrAAyuskUzdAZjGN2ViQtzLV4BRCRWTteLnsFpclSDambqDYcQp4AOQACwgcDg2H9-SAA)